# Subdomains for UK and USA

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers, googlebot

I have a site which is multilingual. I need to target it for visitors from different countries, including United Kingdom and USA.

The problem is that if I make the main site for USA, and subdomain `uk.` for UK, it will contain the same content, and Google will treat it as a duplicate.

I want to also link my subdomains in a footer, like:

```
<a>our site in spain</a>,
<a>our site in english</a>,
<a>our site for UK</a> etc.
```

Will it help in this case or should I use some special meta-tags like `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="..." href="..." />` to avoid actions from Google?

Or should I write different content for every english language version? (other languages' versions will be just translations from the main).

Comment: Incidently, English is what we speak in the UK.  If you call the USA site English and a different one for UK you risk insulting your British customers.

Comment: Google allows (and even rewards) duplicate content when it is targeted at a specific country.  Also see: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: @JamesRyan But we need to target different sites for UK and USA because of specificity of services we provide.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think Google will penalize in any case of duplicate content despite it's usefulness and necessity.

Comment: @Marian I have run sites with the same content duplicated to target US, UK, and AU.  The sites actually ranked a lot better when split like this.  We made some small changes for each country (especially currency for prices) and use Google Webmaster Tools geo targeting features.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for sharing your experience. Will use it to solve the issue.

Comment: @Marian My point wasn't that you shouldn't have 2 sites, but that IF you are going to call only one English then it should be be the English one!  English (UK) and English (USA) might be a better idea.

Comment: @JamesRyan I understood your point of view. Thanks.